# moment-generating function of the chi-square distribution

Tags: probability-distributions

How do we find the moment-generating function of the chi-square distribution?  I really couldn't figure it out.  The integral is

$$E[e^{tX}]=\frac{1}{2^{r/2}\Gamma(r/2)}\int_0^\infty x^{(r-2)/2}e^{-x/2}e^{tx}dx.$$

I'm going over it for a while but can't seem to find the solution.

By the way, the answer should be $$(1-2t)^{(-r/2)}.$$

Comment: You have $E[e^{tX}]$ on the left side of "$=$", and on the right side the letter $t$ is missing!  That should tell you something's wrong.

Comment: silly mistake, i've added e^tx to the end of the integral now. thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
& {}\qquad E[e^{tX}]=\frac{1}{2^{r/2}\Gamma(r/2)}\int_0^\infty x^{(r-2)/2}e^{-x/2}e^{tx}\;dx  \\  \\  \\
& = \frac{1}{2^{r/2}\Gamma(r/2)}\int_0^\infty x^{(r-2)/2}e^{x(t-(1/2))}\;dx \\  \\  \\
& = \frac{1}{2^{r/2}\Gamma(r/2)}\int_0^{-\infty} \left(\frac{u}{t-\frac12}\right)^{(r-2)/2}(e^u)\left(\frac{du}{t-\frac12}\right) \\  \\  \\
& = \frac{1}{2^{r/2}\Gamma(r/2)} \frac{1}{(t-\frac12)^{r/2}} \int_0^{-\infty} u^{(r-2)/2} e^u \; du.
\end{align}
$$
This last integral is a value of the Gamma function.

And notice that
$$
2^{r/2} \left(t-\frac12\right)^{r/2} = (2t-1)^{r/2}.
$$

**Later edit:** Someone questioned the correctness of what is written above; hence these comments.

Notice that as $x$ goes from $0$ to $+\infty$, $u$ will go from $0$ to $-\infty$, since the factor $t-\frac12$ is negative.

Now let $w=-u$, so $u=-w$ and $du=-dw$ and as $u$ goes from $0$ to $-\infty$, then $w$ goes from $0$ to $+\infty$, and we get something that looks like the standard form of the integral that defines the Gamma function.

This still leaves us with the question of raising a negative number to a power.

The fraction $\dfrac{u}{t-\frac12}$ is positive since $u$ and $t-\frac12$ are both negative.  So instead of what was done above, let us substitute $\dfrac{u}{\frac12-t}$ for $x$.  Then $u$ goes from $0$ to $+\infty$ and $e^{x(t-\frac12)}$ will become $e^{-u}$.  Then this should work out without the additional substitution, and we won't have the problem of raising a negative number to a power.

The integral is then $\Gamma(r/2)$, so it cancels that factor in the denominator.

Comment: much thanks, appreciate it!

Comment: btw i think there is a typo after the third line. the integral seems to be in the interval 0 to the plus infinity. and also doesn't the gamma integral has the term $$e^{-u}$$ and not $$e^u$$?

Comment: Since $t-(1/2)$ would be negative, $u$ would go from $0$ to $-\infty$ as $x$ goes from $0$ to $+\infty$.  And you have to do another (trivial) substitution to give it exactly the form in which the definition of the Gamma function is usually written.

Comment: Now I've further edited the answer.  There was an error, but it wasn't where you located it.  It was the problem of raising a negative number to a power.

Comment: I do not know where t is where is it is it flying  to the moon?

Answer (score 5):

In case you have not yet figure it out, the value of the integral follows by simple scaling of the integrand. First, assume $t < \frac{1}{2}$, then change variables $x = (1-2 t) y$:
$$
\int_0^\infty x^{(r-2)/2} \mathrm{e}^{-x/2}\mathrm{e}^{t x}\mathrm{d}x =
 \int_0^\infty x^{r/2} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{(1-2 t) x}{2}} \, \frac{\mathrm{d}x}{x} =
 \left(1-2 t\right)^{-r/2} \int_0^\infty y^{r/2} \mathrm{e}^{-\frac{t}{2}}  \, \frac{\mathrm{d}y}{y}
$$
The integral in $y$ gives the normalization constant, and value of m.g.f. follows.