# Moment generating functions of normal distribution

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

If I have a normal distribution $X$ with mean 0 and variance $\sigma^2$ for $\sigma>0$, how would I find the moment generating function of $Y=X^2$?

I can find the moment generating function of a normal distribution. But I'm not sure how that changes if I'm squaring the distribution.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: The PDF of $Y$ is
$$
f_Y(y)=\frac{1}{\sigma\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\large -\frac{y}{2\sigma^2}}
$$
and the MGF of $Y$ is $$M_Y(t)=\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{1-2\sigma^2t}}.$$

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/289347/321264

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The square of a standard normal distribution is a chi-squared distribution, and its moment generating function can be looked up from here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution

I think you can proceed formally and compute it by $E(e^{tX^{2}})$ by definition as well. This might be easier in practice.

To make matter simple I will do this for the standard normal, we have 
$$
f_{X}(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{x^{2}}{2}}
$$
and we want to integrate
$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{(t-\frac{1}{2})x^{2}}
$$
We can use a scale transformation $u=\sqrt{1-2t}x$. Then we change the integral to be
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{-\frac{u^{2}}{2}}du*\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-2t)}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-2t)}}
$$
as desired. I think the general case is similar.

Comment: I am trying to compute it by $E(e^{tX^{2}})$, but I'm not sure how I would go about doing that. The squared part is what is confusing me.

Comment: You just formally integrate.

Comment: There is a post from the other direction, see here: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71516/moment-generating-function-of-the-chi-square-distribution?rq=1 but the derivation look difficult.

Comment: Sorry I'm still confused. I'm just not sure how to set out the integral.

Comment: Updated. I will leave the general case to you.

Comment: Note that:
$$
\dfrac{X^2}{\sigma^2}\sim\chi^2_1\quad,\text{ if }\mu=0.
$$
**Not**
$$
X^2\sim\chi^2_1.
$$

Comment: Yes, this is a good point. I do not know what the shifted version would be, in fact.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks