# Moment Generating Function $X^2$ and $XY$

Tags: moment-generating-functions

Let X and Y be two independent standard normal random variables.
(a) Find the moment generating function of $X^2$.
(b) Find the moment generating function of $XY$ .
(c) Prove or disprove that $X^2$ and $XY$ have the same distribution.

Kinda confused as to how to do this. For a and b do you just calculate $E[e^{t(x^2)}]$ and $E[e^{t(xy)}]$? Or is there some other way of doing it. Also have no idea how to prove or disprove c.

Comment: See http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/289347/finding-the-moment-generating-function-for-a-random-variable-x2 and http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/71516/moment-generating-function-of-the-chi-square-distribution